# Add template to joomla from directory on server

Tags: templates, joomla

I recently deleted a customised template rom my Joomla installation and am trying to re-install it. The template was merely deleted from the Joomla installation, the files and directories are still on the server and I'm trying to re-install but could not add it through the template manager. I've tried to add it using the Discover function but no luck. It's a Joomlart T3 template btw..

Answer (score 0):

1. Start by downloading the entire template folder via FTP -- www.yoursite.com/templates/your_template
2. Then zip up the contents.
3. Make sure the template is fully uninstalled via Extension Manager
4. Reinstall your zip file via Extension Manager
5. Activate the template

That should do it.